# Unable to detect if Calc.exe is running - Python

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to open a window application when it is not opened in the background. To do that, I need to check if the process is running in the background. I am using pymen to check if the calc.exe is running, and if it's not, I will use subprocess to open a new calc.exe window. However, the code that I am using is not detecting if my calc.exe is actually running or not. It will always be Calculator is Not Running...

```
from pymem import Pymem

try:

    pm = Pymem('calc.exe')
    print('Calculator Started And Is Running....')

except:

    print ('Calculator Is Not Running....')
```

I believe that the code is going through the details tab as shown as below to check if calc.exe is running or not. However, I can't find it in here as well even though the calculator app is running.

[The detail tab in Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV1AV.png)

App like Notepad and Chrome are working fine but calculator. I have no idea why it is not working for calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Microsoft Calculator Windows 10](https://microsoft-calculator-windows-10.peatix.com/):

> The Calculator in non-LTSC editions of Windows 10 is a [Universal
> Windows Platform app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_app). In contrast, Windows 10 LTSC (which does not
> include *universal Windows apps*) includes the traditional calculator,
> but which is now named `win32calc.exe`. … Both the universal Windows
> app and LTSC's `win32calc.exe` register themselves with the system as
> handlers of a '`calculator:`' pseudo-protocol. … 
> All Windows 10
> editions (both LTSC and non-LTSC) continue to have a `calc.exe`, which
> however is just a **stub** that launches (via `ShellExecute`) the
> handler that is associated with the '`calculator:`' pseudo-protocol.

In other words, `calc.exe` is merely a wrapper which launches another executable:

```
import psutil
import subprocess
import time


def list_calc(phase):
    print(phase)
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name().startswith( PROCNAME):
            print( proc.name())
            print( proc.cmdline()[0])
            if proc.name() == 'CalculatorApp.exe':
                proc.kill()


PROCNAME = 'Calc'

list_calc('- before:')

calc = subprocess.Popen([PROCNAME+'.exe'])
time.sleep(3) # wait until calculator window appears

list_calc('- after:')
```

**Result**: `ver && .\SO\75191242.py`

> ```
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2486]
> - before:
> - after:
> CalculatorApp.exe
> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_11.2210.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\CalculatorApp.exe
> ```